# Hausdorff spaces with lattice isomorphism between the topologies

Tags: gn.general-topology, lattice-theory

For $i=1,2$ let $(X_i,\tau_i)$ be Hausdorff spaces such that the lattices $\tau_1, \tau_2$ are isomorphic.

Does this imply that $(X_1, \tau_1) \cong (X_2,\tau_2)$?

(This is a follow-up question to [$T_2$-spaces such that the lattices of open sets can be embedded into each other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213073/t-2-spaces-such-that-the-lattices-of-open-sets-can-be-embedded-into-each-other).)

Comment: Yes, Hausdorff spaces are sober.